# JS | Проверка на заглвные буквы в строке

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста с проверкой на JS. Как лучше и короче проверить строку на заглавные буквы? Регулярное выражение и перебор в цикле или как?

```
var stroka = "pokVRPOVkw439ujgIOOPR" //Рандомная строка в которой есть заглавные буквы, после проверки должна дать true
var stroka = "qwerty34аujikkjhg555fdcvxbbnmasdf" //Строка в которой только маленькие буквы, должна дать false
```

Comment: Какие конкретно заглавные буквы вас интересуют? Только английские или все, которые в юникоде считаются заглавными?

Comment: Лучше все конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. Приводим строку к нижнему регистру и сравниваем с исходной:

```js
const hasCapital = (s) => !(s === s.toLowerCase());

console.log(hasCapital('pokVRPOVkw439ujgIOOPR'));
console.log(hasCapital('qwerty34аujikkjhg555fdcvxqbbnmasdf'));
```

Вариант 2. Регулярное выражение:

```js
const hasCapital = (s) => !/^[a-zа-я\d]*$/.test(s);

console.log(hasCapital('pokVRPOVkw439ujgIOOPR'));
console.log(hasCapital('qwerty34аujikkjhg555fdcvxqbbnmasdf'));
```

`[a-zа-я\d]*` - строка может содержать буквы в нижнем регистре и/или цифры, или быть пустой.

**UPD**
@andreymal в комментарии справедливо указал на спецсимволы, букву Ё и пустую строку. Если требуется их учесть, то используем другое выражение:

```js
const hasCapital = (s) => !/^[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*$/.test(s);
```

Comment: Первое решение очевидно неэффективное, а второе не учитывает возможность существования спецсимволов

Comment: @andreymal Вопрос был про буквы. Цифру в задании увидел, поэтому добавил. А пробелы? `^[^A-ZА-Я]+$` - так лучше?

Comment: Возможно лучше, но букву Ё забыли

Comment: @andreymal Не мучайте, выкладывайте всё, что знаете )

Comment: Да, пробелы тоже нужны

Comment: Почему первое не эффективное? В каких вариантах оно может не сработать?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКорчагина я не говорил что оно может не сработать, просто создание целой преобразованной копии строки ради одной лишь проверки букв это пустая трата процессорного времени

Comment: Cпасибо, Андрей!) Ладно, других вариантов все равно нет, беру первый

Comment: @andreymal Проверил [тут](https://jsbench.github.io/). Взял достаточно длинную строку, первый вариант шустрее в 40 раз. Полагаю, Екатерина выбрала верный вариант.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey странный результат, не ожидал такой подставы от регулярок

Comment: Кстати заметил ещё косяк — варианты с регуляркой возвращают true для пустой строки

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо. Квантификатор не углядел, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - перевести строку в нижний регистр и сравнить с исходной.

```js
const str = "pokVRPOVkw439ujgIOOPR";
const str2 = "qwerty34аujikkjhg555fdcvxbbnmasdf";

function checkContainsUppercaseLetters(str) {
  return !!str.localeCompare(str.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(checkContainsUppercaseLetters(str));
console.log(checkContainsUppercaseLetters(str2));
```